# Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver) is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class testTime extends runAutomation{

    static WebElement element = null;
    static String driverPath = "<Path>//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe";
    static String username = null;
    static String password = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
        options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("URL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        SixLabels page = new SixLabels();
        page.doLogin();
    }
} 

public class SixLabels extends testTime{
    static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    public static WebElement userName(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("UserName"));
        return element ;
    }

    public static WebElement password(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
        return element ;
    }

    private void adminMenuClick(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)     
            .pollingEvery(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)       
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);         
        WebElement waitingElement = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, 
        WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(By.linkText("ADMINISTRATIVE MODULE"));
            }
        });
        waitingElement.click();
}

    public void doLogin() throws InterruptedException{
        userName(driver);
        element.sendKeys("uname");
        Password(driver);
        element.sendKeys("@password");
        LoginButton(driver);
        element.click();
        adminMenuClick(driver);
    }
}
```

Many people suggested to place  `Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)` to wait for the element to be available for click.But that is not working when i try to use this. I have to put Thread.sleep(4000); explicitly in the between each click. Can some one give me correct solution please

Comment: Nothing personal, but there are so many things wrong with this code I don't even know where to begin.  I strongly suggest that you take a Selenium video training course.  There are tons of them out there, many for free, most of them good. I admire your wanting to learn this but this example is non-functional on many levels.

Comment: Okay Bill....Not an issue can you pls correct hence I can use that and see where I went wrong please .....But thanks for correcting that i am doing it incorrectly...do you suggest any thing good one  links for such training.